# How to make SQL Server Connection (not from file) appear in ADO.Net Connection Model Wizard?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add a connection to Adventureworks on a new development machine running VS 2010. I have SSMS running and am able to query the Adventureworks database. However,  when I click “New Connection” (steps followed below after *) , I do not see SQL Server connection as an option.  Is there a way to configure VS 2010 so that it sees my localhost connection to SQL Server?

Second option:
When I try using the option Microsoft SQL Server from database file, whenever I browse to the mdf file for Adventureworks, I always see the message 'file in use', even though I have only one instance of VS 2010 open and SSMS is closed.

- steps i followed were
  new project
  class library
  right click solution explorer
  add 
  new item
  ado.net entity data management
  new connection

Comment: Can you please, give us your exact visual studio version (premium, web edition , SP 1 etc). Also please  clarify your steps with comma's or something. Sql Server should be there if I understand you right. I chose: http://picpaste.com/Naamloos-L4CHLhtG.png

Answer (score 0):

Just type in localhost as the server name, test the connection and click Ok. It will be saved, next time it will appear in the list.

- The Data Source type is set to  "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)"

If this doesn't pop up in your screen then install SQl Server Native Client here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff658533.aspx

Comment: thanks for the response! However - where do you type Locaohost as the servername? that option seems not to exist when you can only do database from file - not from SQL Server connection. trying second option now...